# arduino Ultrasound srf05 wrong value

Tags: arduino

My Arduino board is Arduino Due ATmega328p. My Ultrasound is `srf05`.

I measure the distance is 5cm but my serial show me "531".Serial Monitor show the int of distance which value is always be 531.Why?

Here are the codes.

```
#define ECHOPIN 2                            // Pin to receive echo pulse    
#define TRIGPIN 3                            // Pin to send trigger pulse

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ECHOPIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(TRIGPIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, LOW);                   // Set the trigger pin to low for 2uS
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, HIGH);                  // Send a 10uS high to trigger ranging
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, LOW);                   // Send pin low again
  int distance = pulseIn(ECHOPIN, HIGH);        // Read in times pulse

  distance = distance/58;                        // Calculate distance from time of pulse
  Serial.println(distance);                     
  delay(50);                                    // Wait 50mS before next ranging
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The srf05 times out if it doesn't receive the echo pulse. The width of the pulse is 30 ms.

30,000 / 58 is 517, which is close to 531. It looks like your device is not receiving an echo from the object. This makes your problem a hardware issue, and not a programming issue. (The code looks correct.)